# nodejs xmlrpc error: Error: XML-RPC fault: Multiple source template were found from input data:

Tags: xml, node.js, web-services, rpc, webservice-client

I'm trying to consume an xmlrpc webservice from a node app (*shakes head and looks down*) and I'm running into some issues. This is the payload I want to fire off:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:m="urn:ActionWebService" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <VmProvisionRequest xmlns="urn:ActionWebService">
      <version xsi:type="xsd:string">1.1</version>
<templateFields xsi:type="xsd:string">blah blah</templateFields>
<vmFields xsi:type="xsd:string">blah blah</vmFields>
<requester xsi:type="xsd:string">blah blah</requester>
<tags xsi:type="xsd:string"></tags>
<options xsi:type="m:VmdbwsSupport..ProvisionOptions">
      <values xsi:type="xsd:string"></values>
      <ems_custom_attributes xsi:type="xsd:string"></ems_custom_attributes>
      <miq_custom_attributes xsi:type="xsd:string">blah blah</miq_custom_attributes>
      </options>
    </VmProvisionRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But in the [xmlrpc lib for node](https://github.com/baalexander/node-xmlrpc), when I make a methodCall on a client, I can only pass params (an array list that is iterated over to generate xml in [serializer](https://github.com/baalexander/node-xmlrpc/blob/master/lib/serializer.js)??)

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
var xmlrpc = require('xmlrpc')

var request =  '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:m="urn:ActionWebService" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">'+
'<SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
'<VmProvisionRequest xmlns="urn:ActionWebService">' +
  '<version xsi:type="xsd:string">1.1</version>' +
'<templateFields xsi:type="xsd:string">blah blah</templateFields>' +
'<vmFields xsi:type="xsd:string">blah blah</vmFields>' +
'<requester xsi:type="xsd:string">blah blah</requester>' +
'<tags xsi:type="xsd:string"></tags>' +
'<options xsi:type="m:VmdbwsSupport..ProvisionOptions">' +
  '<values xsi:type="xsd:string"></values>' +
  '<ems_custom_attributes xsi:type="xsd:string"></ems_custom_attributes>' +
  '<miq_custom_attributes xsi:type="xsd:string">blah blah</miq_custom_attributes>' +
  '</options>' +
'</VmProvisionRequest>' +
'</SOAP-ENV:Body>' +
'</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'

// Creates an XML-RPC client. Passes the host information on where to
// make the XML-RPC calls.

var clientOps = {
            host: 'myhost',
            port: 443,
            path: '/vmdbws/api',
            basic_auth: {
                user: 'username',
                pass: 'password',
            }
    };

var client = xmlrpc.createSecureClient(clientOps);

// Sends a method call to the XML-RPC server
client.methodCall('VmProvisionRequest', request, function (error, value) {
    if (error){
        console.log(error);
    }
  // Results of the method response
  console.log('Method response for VmProvisionRequest: ' + value)
})
```

I see this error:

```
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
starting engines
{ [Error: XML-RPC fault: Multiple source template were found from input data:<{}>]
  code: 2,
  faultCode: 2,
  faultString: 'Multiple source template were found from input data:<{}>' }
Method response for VmProvisionRequest: undefined
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 0
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!